# Django Template Language: Create conditional for entire Model (not record by record)

Tags: django, django-templates

Newbie problem. Per the following script in a template ...

```
{% if request.user not in Result %}
     <p>You have no account in the system.</p>
{% endif %}
```

... the statement "You have no account in the system." is appearing 100 times on screen---because there are 100 records and therefore the condition is being checked 100 times.

Is there a way to modify the script so that the statement appears just once? Meaning, it checks the entire database once for evidence that request.user appears anywhere in the model in aggregrate (and not whether it appears in each of the 100 records in the database)?

Maybe there's an easier/better way to do this in views.py vs a template, but that's beyond my knowledge. Thank you. Below is the model called Result.

models.py

```
 class Result(models.Model):
     custom_user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, default=None, 
                   null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
     decision = models.ForeignKey(Decision, default=None, 
                null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                             verbose_name="Decision")
     vote_eligible = models.BooleanField(default=True)
     vote = models.CharField(default="", max_length=100, 
                             blank=True, verbose_name="Your 
                             Vote:")
     voted_already = models.BooleanField(default=False)

     @staticmethod
     def get_absolute_url():
         return "/home"

     def __str__(self):
         return f"{self.custom_user}"
```

views.py

```
class VoteForm(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Result
    form_class = VotingForm
    template_name = 'users/vote_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context["Result"] = Result.objects.all()
        return context
```

forms.py

```
class VotingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Result
        fields = ['decision', 'vote']
```

Comment: Could you please post , what myModel conatins?

Comment: Yes, please see myModel (named Result) above.  Note that the foreign field, custom_user, is an email address (i.e., same format as request.user). Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: Sorry my bad, I was supposed to write views code, mistakenly I have mentioned model. Coudl you please post your views code that rendering the context to template

Comment: Above I just posted views.py and forms.py. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

views.py

Since the requirement is to display whether the logged in user has account in 'Result' model or not. I have filtered the rows specific to the user. You can loop over the user_specific in your template. If user is present in 'Result' model 'user_specifc' will have elements. If user is not present in 'Result' table, 'user_specific' will be empty. In you template, you can check whether 'user_specific' is empty list or not.

```
class VoteForm(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Result
    form_class = VotingForm
    template_name = 'users/vote_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context["Result"] = Result.objects.all()
        context['user_specific'] = Result.objects.filter(custom_user=self.request.user)
        return context
```

template.html

```
{% if not user_specific %}
     <p>You have no account in the system.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That worked! And thanks for improving my knowledge of the get_context_data method.